# Can not start xConnect Index Worker during Sc 9.3 XP0 local installation - FormatException

Tags: xconnect, installation

During the `SC 9.3 installation (XP0 local) via SIF and SIA` I receive this cannot-start-service error at the last third of the installation:

```
[--------------------------- XConnectXP0_StartServices [1] : ManageService -------------------------------------------]
[XConnectXP0_StartServices [1]]:[Updating] Sc93SxaSg.xconnect-IndexWorker
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - Sc93SxaSg.xconnect-IndexWorker 
(Sc93SxaSg.xconnect-IndexWorker)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service 
Sc93SxaSg.xconnect-IndexWorker on computer '.'.
At C:\Sitecore\Setup\Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (WDP XP0 packages)\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:77 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:04:29

Start-Service : Service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - Sc93SxaSg.xconnect-IndexWorker
(Sc93SxaSg.xconnect-IndexWorker)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service
Sc93SxaSg.xconnect-IndexWorker on computer '.'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.2.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-ManageServiceTask.ps1:40 char:33
+                     $instance | Start-Service
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
       ServiceCommandException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Going deeper, when I call xConnect via browser I receive a FormatException:

[image]

at `Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.ConvertBase64LicenseFile(String encodedLicense)
calling System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode()`

I have no clue now what could be the issue now.... License files not expired, .NET Core 2.1.x .NET 4.8 are installed, SIF Version is 2.2.0

What i have also tried/checked:

- Checked for untrusted certificates
- Checked all xConnect license files (also in the job folder) and if they are not expired
- Prerequisites have are all installed before SC installation via SIF 
  Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\prerequisites.json
- Checked .NET Versions

Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like your license file is not correct. Can you copy it from any server/system where it's working?

Comment: Do you have a valid License file?

Comment: Thanks, I copied one of a running system (9.2) and still the same format exception. I also used this one for a new installation from beginning but same error. The license file is not expired, expiration date is far in the future

Comment: The error is not about expiration, though. It appears like it has some invalid characters that the code is not expecting. I would make sure you contact support and get them to validate that your license file can be processed correctly. You may need an updated license file in a better format, or there could be an issue with the license reading code that is not expecting something in your license file.

Comment: Does your license have xDB.Base in it? That is the flag that turns on xDB.

Comment: Thanks, yes xDB.Base is in our license file included. I think now it could only be an issue in the license reading code, since this license file is working in a 9.2 instance. But will also try to get this license file validated by the support. Thank you a lot. I will now examine this in more detail, will let you know if I found out something new.

Comment: Interesting! Once you get a reply from Sitecore Support, please post it as an answer to this. It will definitely help in giving direction to anyone else who faces the same.